# Setting Permissions on a new kali user

Tags: kali-linux, audio, raspberry-pi, non-root-user

What I would like to know in clear detail and easy to understand wording. How can I add permissions from the root account on kali(ARM) for a PI3. I also want my new account to have full permissions and sudo but I cant seem to understand how to set permissions or set sudo for it. I am trying to fix my sound and want to test it with a none root account.

Comment: What do you mean by "full permissions and sudo"? You want the new user to have permission to run any command with sudo, or are you referring to some other place for "full permissions"?

Answer (score 3):

Setting up permissions can get confusing, but it's really not. In general you need to do three things:

**Create the User**

```
useradd -d /home/someuser -s /bin/bash someuser
sudo mkdir /home/someuser
```

This will setup a new user "some user" with a home dir at `/home/someuser/` and using bash as the default shell.

**Set the user as a sudoer**

```
visudo
```

This will open `/etc/sudoers` in nano. If you have a different editor you could always use that. Add the following the file under the "root" entry.

```
someuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Save the file, and now your new user `someuser` is a sudoer.

**Set the new user's password**

To finalize this process, add a password for the user so they can sudo. If they want to change the password later they can with the `sudo passwd` command.

```
sudo passwd someuser
-- then enter password && conf
```

Your new user now has the ability to sudo access the everything root can. You can event `sudo su` to act as root. To test it out, logout of Kali as root and log back in as your new user. Or, just run `su - someuser` and try sudoing.

Also - give your new user ownership of their home dir using `chown -R someuser /home/someuser`

Comment: You can also save some typing by using `-m` instead of `-d /home/someuser`, if you want the new dir to be in BASEDIR (usually /home) and the new dir name to be the same as the username.

Comment: This right here is what I wanted now let me try to make it work before I say thank you so if i get stuck I can still ask for help.

to the person who asked what i mean by full permissions I mean so i do not need to be in root to do what I want like for example if I make an user in a Linux mint right from the start it can do every thing I want with out me setting any thing up. Thats all i want

Comment: also what do you mean bash? I am kind of basic to Linux I just love the UI and the lay out of kali is why I wanted to use that before you ask why I am using the distro that I am.

Comment: hey  guys thank you I am about to test it and see if the stepped worked I think it did as it gave me no errors so lets see.

----- its working but its only trying to call one file for updating not the long long list of things whats wrong.

and also I still do not have sound

Comment: @Kawar - Bash is the default shell used in the Kali ARM distribution. If you're unfamiliar, just google "bash" and "unix shells". To start acting as the new user on the Kali desktop, you'll have to logout and login at the start screen with your new username/pass. If this answered your question, please accept it as the correct answer.